# Can't assign a value to a variable of type integer

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the prime numbers from 1 to 100. The problem I encounter is that when the program assigns the value 2 to the variable j of type integer. The value of variable j does not change. Does anyone know why this happens?

> Create a program to find all the prime numbers between 1 and 100.
>
> One way to do this is to write a function that will check if a number is
> prime (i.e., see if the number can be divided by a prime number
> smaller than itself) using a vector of primes in order (so that if the
> vector is called primes, primes[0]==2, primes[1]==3, primes[2]==5,
> etc.). Then write a loop that goes from 1 to 100, checks each number
> to see if it is a prime, and stores each prime found in a vector.
> Write another loop that lists the primes you found. You might check
> your result by comparing your vector of prime numbers with primes.
> Consider 2 the first prime.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> primes = { 2 };
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; ++i) 
        for (int j = 2; j < i; ++j) 
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;
            else
                primes.push_back(j);
    for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << primes[i] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: *How* do you know the value of `j` doesn't change? Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: I think I now have a real problem is that the results are not what I want.

Comment: Also note that you will add lots of duplicates to your vector. You might want to rethink your algorithm. This is probably your problem.

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us the expected *and* actual result. Maybe not in full but at least an example of the expected and actual result.

Comment: For each `i`, you're storing every number it's not divisible with. That is, your code says, "since 6 isn't divisible with 4 or 5, 4 and 5 are prime". (`i % j == 0` means that `j` is a factor of `i`; `i % j != 0` does not mean that `j` is prime, only that `i` *might* be.)

Answer (score 4):

There are some mistakes in your initial implementation:

- You are adding elements too soon in the `primes` vector
- You don't have a clear definition of whatever you consider a prime
- You are trying to put everything in a single function

Some more cleaned up code would look a bit similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace {
    bool isPrime(const std::vector<int> &previousPrimes, int possiblePrime) {
        for (auto prevPrime : previousPrimes)
            if (possiblePrime % prevPrime == 0)
               return false;

        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto primes = std::vector<int>({2});
    for (int i = 3 /*2 is already a prime*/; i <= 100; ++i)
        if (isPrime(primes, i))
           primes.push_back(i);

    for (auto prime : primes)
        std::cout << prime << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

However, as this question looks like a homework assignment, don't blindly copy this and try to understand all the concepts used in here first.

Comment: Note:  You can increment by 2 since all even numbers (except 2) are not primes.

Comment: What do the keyword 'auto' and 'namespace' do?

Comment: @HermanTam: See [Unnamed namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/495/namespaces/4851/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces) + [auto](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/2421/auto).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> primes;
  primes.push_back(2);
  for(int i=3; i < 100; i++)
  {
      bool prime=true;
      for(int j=0;j<primes.size() && primes[j]*primes[j] <= i;j++)
      {
          if(i % primes[j] == 0)
          {
             prime=false;
             break;
          }
      }
      if(prime) 
      {
         primes.push_back(i);
         std::cout << i << " ";
      }
  }

   return 0;
}
```

this will print the fallowing :

```
3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

We keep track of all of our previously calculated primes. If a number is divisible by a non-prime number, there is also some prime <= that divisor which it is also divisble by. This reduces computation by a factor of primes_in_range/total_range.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is written in the assignment that you have **to write a function** that checks whether a number is prime using a vector of prime numbers.

This loop

```
   for (int j = 2; j < i; ++j) 
        if (i % j == 0)
            break;
        else
            primes.push_back(j);
```

does not make sense because it does not use the vector to check whether `i` is divisible by an element of the vector. Also a new prime number should be added to the vector after the loop provided that I is divisible by neither element of the vector.

Also take into account that there is written in the assignment

> Then write a loop that goes **from 1 to 100**, checks each number to
>   see if it is a prime

Thus only my code shown below satisfies the assignment.:)

The program can look the following way. Instead of type `int` I used type `unsigned int` because you are checking only non-negative values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool is_prime( const std::vector<unsigned int> &primes, unsigned int x )
{
    std::vector<unsigned int>::size_type i = 0;

    while ( i < primes.size() && x % primes[i] != 0 ) ++i;

    return x != 1 && i == primes.size();        
}


int main() 
{
    const unsigned int N = 100;
    std::vector<unsigned int> primes;

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; ++i )
    {

        if ( is_prime( primes, i ) ) primes.push_back( i );
    }

    for ( unsigned int x : primes ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Thank you for all your answers, but I just figured out why. The codes are following:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> primes = { 2 };
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; ++i) 
        for (int j = 2; j < i; ++j) {
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;
            if (j == i - 1)
                primes.push_back(i);
        }
    for (int x: primes)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I just figured that out myself

Comment: Do you think my codes are short, simple, and easy to understand?

Comment: See one more my answer. I pointed out how the assignment must be performed.:) It is the only answer that satisfies the assignment description.:)

Comment: You have to fill the vector using a sequence of unsigned numbers started from 1. Initially the vector should be empty.

Comment: @HermanTam Actually that is a question for on codereview.stackexchange.com though that aside, if I would do a code review, you would get following remarks: Add comments, try making this more performant and try to put the 'isPrime' logic in a separate function to allow reusing it later on.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have already post it on codereview.stackexchange.com, the link is following: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138542/find-prime-numbers-from-1-to-100